# WeatherStack API get weather descriptions

Tags: weatherstack

I wanted to get WeatherStack API's weather descriptions in order to translate them in my local language. Is it possible to do with a GET call (example: from Postman) or do I have to search into their documentation?

I've tried removing the current?access-key from the URL for the API call and adding weather_descriptions at the end of the URL, obtaining one like this:

`http://api.weatherstack.com/weather_descriptions`

but without an access-key I couldn't make a GET call. I re-add it, keep `weather_descriptions` at the end but with an URL like this

`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=my-access-key/weather-descriptions`

it still gives an error

Answer (score 0):

@BaCplusplush you need to register yourself to get WeatherStack api-key. Without api-key you can not call any API.

Also you need to check their API documentation and figure which API suits your requirement and accordingly you can use it.

Comment: I'm already registered to WeatherStack and a general GET call can be done, but I was wondering if their weather_descriptions list could be obtained via GET as well